# Meteor : lukemadera:social-share package not allowing to share from Localhost domain

Tags: meteor

I am using 'lukemadera:social-share' atmosphere package but thing is it is not allowing me to share anything from localhost giving error => this feature is not available and also subject and body sent from sharedata is not posting only link is posted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error says itself "this feature is not available". i.e. it's the limitation of the package. And, I guess social sharing is not allowed from localhost, at least Facebook doesn't allow this!

Comment: Thank you and also facebook is not accepting parameters to share links we can not add title,summary etc. If you know any way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Social Shares(facebook/google) **DO NOT ALLOW to SHARE from LOCALHOST domain**. Even facebook api(eg.fb.api) not allows to share data from localhost. So use packages/api of social share at ***production*** side.